# Cannot Validate A Simple Custom XML File

Tags: xml, validation, rss, feed

I have spent the past two hours and read hundreds of pages of gibberish trying to make any sense of how to validate the simplest custom XML, and feel like I'm further behind than when I started.  I read that on something simple, a namespace isn't required, yet the validator keeps giving me errors about undefined namespaces and "undefined root element jobs."  Originally had "jobs" as "feed" which told me I had to specify a namespace, and every single one I tried made the validation output even worse...so I changed it to "jobs" now but it tells me that is undefined.  I don't know what it wants me to do.

I have a very simple structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jobs>
    <job>
        <jobtitle>General Manager</jobtitle>
        <jobcity>Atlanta</jobcity>
        <jobstate>GA</jobstate>
        <jobdescription><![CDATA[Description text here.]]></jobdescription>
        <joblink>http://domain.com</joblink>
    </job>
</jobs>
```

What do I need to do to make this validate?

Comment: What are using to do the validation? Do you have a DTD or schema that the XML should validate against?

Answer (score 0):

You should validate **against** some rules. This rules can be in form of:

- DTD
- XSD schema

For example I generate DTD for your simple xml and get new xml with rules insude:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jobs [
        <!ELEMENT jobs (job)*>
        <!ELEMENT job (jobtitle|jobcity|jobstate|jobdescription|joblink)*>
        <!ELEMENT jobtitle (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT jobcity (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT jobstate (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT jobdescription (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT joblink (#PCDATA)>
        ]>
<jobs>
    <job>
        <jobtitle>General Manager</jobtitle>
        <jobcity>Atlanta</jobcity>
        <jobstate>GA</jobstate>
        <jobdescription><![CDATA[Description text here.]]></jobdescription>
        <joblink>http://domain.com</joblink>
    </job>
</jobs>
```

Also I generate XSD schema for your xml. You can prefer to use XSD because it's more powerful tool for validation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="jobs" type="jobsType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="jobType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="jobtitle"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="jobcity"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="jobstate"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="jobdescription"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="joblink"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="jobsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="jobType" name="job"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```